# What is the FeeReason enumeration in the Bitcoin Core?

Tags: transaction-fees, bitcoin-core-development, source-code

[There](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/policy/fees.h#L44) is enumeration called `FeeReason`. What is it? What is its use cases?

```
/* Enumeration of reason for returned fee estimate */
enum class FeeReason {
    NONE,
    HALF_ESTIMATE,
    FULL_ESTIMATE,
    DOUBLE_ESTIMATE,
    CONSERVATIVE,
    MEMPOOL_MIN,
    PAYTXFEE,
    FALLBACK,
    REQUIRED,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is used to report back to callers into the fee estimation functions to learn why the returned feerate was chosen. Descriptions for these reasons are:

```
static const std::map<FeeReason, std::string> fee_reason_strings = {
    {FeeReason::NONE, "None"},
    {FeeReason::HALF_ESTIMATE, "Half Target 60% Threshold"},
    {FeeReason::FULL_ESTIMATE, "Target 85% Threshold"},
    {FeeReason::DOUBLE_ESTIMATE, "Double Target 95% Threshold"},
    {FeeReason::CONSERVATIVE, "Conservative Double Target longer horizon"},
    {FeeReason::MEMPOOL_MIN, "Mempool Min Fee"},
    {FeeReason::PAYTXFEE, "PayTxFee set"},
    {FeeReason::FALLBACK, "Fallback fee"},
    {FeeReason::REQUIRED, "Minimum Required Fee"},
};
```

Comment: Is there any document or resource to learn more about these reasons? What does each of them mean?